# pip installations issues on MacOS with new m1 chip

Tags: python, macos, pip, apple-m1

I just switched from Windows to Mac and cloned my repository. I have the Mac Mini 2020 with the new m1 chip.

I ran `pip3 install -r requirements.txt` and got the following error:

```
    ERROR: Command errored out with exit status 1:
     command: /Library/Developer/CommandLineTools/usr/bin/python3 -c 'import sys, setuptools, tokenize; sys.argv[0] = '"'"'/private/var/folders/t9/czy9qvr930l9s46j8b9k__th0000gp/T/pip-install-npqzencr/mysqlclient/setup.py'"'"'; __file__='"'"'/private/var/folders/t9/czy9qvr930l9s46j8b9k__th0000gp/T/pip-install-npqzencr/mysqlclient/setup.py'"'"';f=getattr(tokenize, '"'"'open'"'"', open)(__file__);code=f.read().replace('"'"'\r\n'"'"', '"'"'\n'"'"');f.close();exec(compile(code, __file__, '"'"'exec'"'"'))' egg_info --egg-base pip-egg-info
         cwd: /private/var/folders/t9/czy9qvr930l9s46j8b9k__th0000gp/T/pip-install-npqzencr/mysqlclient/
    Complete output (15 lines):
    /bin/sh: mysql_config: command not found
    /bin/sh: mariadb_config: command not found
    /bin/sh: mysql_config: command not found
    Traceback (most recent call last):
      File "<string>", line 1, in <module>
      File "/private/var/folders/t9/czy9qvr930l9s46j8b9k__th0000gp/T/pip-install-npqzencr/mysqlclient/setup.py", line 15, in <module>
        metadata, options = get_config()
      File "/private/var/folders/t9/czy9qvr930l9s46j8b9k__th0000gp/T/pip-install-npqzencr/mysqlclient/setup_posix.py", line 70, in get_config
        libs = mysql_config("libs")
      File "/private/var/folders/t9/czy9qvr930l9s46j8b9k__th0000gp/T/pip-install-npqzencr/mysqlclient/setup_posix.py", line 31, in mysql_config
        raise OSError("{} not found".format(_mysql_config_path))
    OSError: mysql_config not found
    mysql_config --version
    mariadb_config --version
    mysql_config --libs
    ----------------------------------------
ERROR: Command errored out with exit status 1: python setup.py egg_info Check the logs for full command output.
```

I tried with sudo after seeing another post about this issue:
`sudo pip3 install -r requirements.txt` and got this error:

```
    ERROR: Command errored out with exit status 1:
     command: /Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.9/bin/python3.9 -c 'import io, os, sys, setuptools, tokenize; sys.argv[0] = '"'"'/private/tmp/pip-install-jqyr1k_y/mysqlclient_c6d45690ebfd45cdbd081164dcfad4ce/setup.py'"'"'; __file__='"'"'/private/tmp/pip-install-jqyr1k_y/mysqlclient_c6d45690ebfd45cdbd081164dcfad4ce/setup.py'"'"';f = getattr(tokenize, '"'"'open'"'"', open)(__file__) if os.path.exists(__file__) else io.StringIO('"'"'from setuptools import setup; setup()'"'"');code = f.read().replace('"'"'\r\n'"'"', '"'"'\n'"'"');f.close();exec(compile(code, __file__, '"'"'exec'"'"'))' egg_info --egg-base /private/tmp/pip-pip-egg-info-h6hpe889
         cwd: /private/tmp/pip-install-jqyr1k_y/mysqlclient_c6d45690ebfd45cdbd081164dcfad4ce/
    Complete output (15 lines):
    /bin/sh: mysql_config: command not found
    /bin/sh: mariadb_config: command not found
    /bin/sh: mysql_config: command not found
    Traceback (most recent call last):
      File "<string>", line 1, in <module>
      File "/private/tmp/pip-install-jqyr1k_y/mysqlclient_c6d45690ebfd45cdbd081164dcfad4ce/setup.py", line 15, in <module>
        metadata, options = get_config()
      File "/private/tmp/pip-install-jqyr1k_y/mysqlclient_c6d45690ebfd45cdbd081164dcfad4ce/setup_posix.py", line 70, in get_config
        libs = mysql_config("libs")
      File "/private/tmp/pip-install-jqyr1k_y/mysqlclient_c6d45690ebfd45cdbd081164dcfad4ce/setup_posix.py", line 31, in mysql_config
        raise OSError("{} not found".format(_mysql_config_path))
    OSError: mysql_config not found
    mysql_config --version
    mariadb_config --version
    mysql_config --libs
    ----------------------------------------
WARNING: Discarding https://files.pythonhosted.org/packages/3c/df/59cd2fa5e48d0804d213bdcb1acb4d08c403b61c7ff7ed4dd4a6a2deb3f7/mysqlclient-2.0.3.tar.gz#sha256=f6ebea7c008f155baeefe16c56cd3ee6239f7a5a9ae42396c2f1860f08a7c432 (from https://pypi.org/simple/mysqlclient/) (requires-python:>=3.5). Command errored out with exit status 1: python setup.py egg_info Check the logs for full command output.
ERROR: Could not find a version that satisfies the requirement mysqlclient==2.0.3 (from versions: 1.3.0, 1.3.1, 1.3.2, 1.3.3, 1.3.4, 1.3.5, 1.3.6, 1.3.7, 1.3.8, 1.3.9, 1.3.10, 1.3.11rc1, 1.3.11, 1.3.12, 1.3.13, 1.3.14, 1.4.0rc1, 1.4.0rc2, 1.4.0rc3, 1.4.0, 1.4.1, 1.4.2, 1.4.2.post1, 1.4.3, 1.4.4, 1.4.5, 1.4.6, 2.0.0, 2.0.1, 2.0.2, 2.0.3)
ERROR: No matching distribution found for mysqlclient==2.0.3
```

Versions:
Python 2.7.16
pip 19.2.3
When I run check my pip version it clearly shows python 3.8 there:

```
pip3 --version
pip 19.2.3 from /Library/Developer/CommandLineTools/Library/Frameworks/Python3.framework/Versions/3.8/lib/python3.8/site-packages/pip (python 3.8)
```

Any tips would be LOVELY!

Answer (score 1):

I’ve also had similar experience with M1. I think it’s due to the mysql config. So first of all locate where your `mysql_config` is ( it can either be in `/opt` or `/bin` directories). For instance mine is in:

```
/opt/homebrew/bin
```

Once you’ve found the file, you need to edit the file with your favorite editor (I use `nano`) and change this line in the configuration:

```
# Create options 
libs="-L$pkglibdir" 
libs="$libs -l "
```

change it to this:

```
# Create options
libs="-L$pkglibdir" 
libs="$libs -lmysqlclient -lssl -lcrypto"
```

after editing install `mysqlclient` again. You can also ensure that `gcc` is already installed on your Mac